# Silverlight 2 datagrid headers

Tags: c#, silverlight

Is there a way to change the column headers of a SL2 datagrid during databinding? I'm looking for something similar to ASP.net's rowDataBound, I'm looking at _LoadingRow is this the correct event?

Comment: can you provide more detail? Change in what way?

Comment: Why would you change column headers based on row data. Binding/changing column headers should not be row driven.

Comment: Jeff, for example as my list binds to the grid, I would like to do something similar to this: 

if(e.Row.HeaderText = "_app")
 e.Row.SetHeaderText = "Application";

I'm binding from a custom collection and want to clean up the header names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [rAyt in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977971/silverlight-2-datagrid-headers/977984#977984), you can add bindings to the columns. With an appropriate binding and possibly a value converter, you could use this mechanism to update the headers.

You can also [set the `DataGrid` to auto-generate columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns(VS.95).aspx) based on the collection data. You may find this a better route. You can also modify the auto-generated columns as described by [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903950(VS.95).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can bind DataColumns in your XAML

```
 <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Latitude" Binding="{Binding lat}"  IsReadOnly="True"  />
```